# How to manage nested routes with private route in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a login page once user click on login button that will be direct login and go to dashboard page. Now I'm faccing issue with nested routes, I mean after login there is two menus in left side of dashboard.

- When user will click on Users link then right side only users component should be render
- When user will click on Products link then right side only products component should be render
- currently Users and Products both component rendering together.

[Sandbox URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-water-230wql?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Well your `layout` component is rendering both components, so you'll see them both.

Comment: You should create a route for each seperate route that will only render 1 component, let thet component also render the menu. Or create a wrapper that will always inject the menu.

Comment: This question is off-topic because the code is not in the question. Voting to close for now. Would you add a code block please Rohit?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the nested routes. Please check the following code

App.jsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path="" element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path="/layout" element={<Layout />} />
          <Route path="/user" element={<Users />} />
          <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Layout.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Col, Row } from "antd";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col xxl={4} xl={5} lg={6} md={6} sm={6} xs={6}>
          <div className="left-menu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/user">Users</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/products">Products</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

SignIn.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Users = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const loginAuth = () => {
    navigate("/layout");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Sign In</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
      <button onClick={loginAuth}>Login</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Users;
```

Please check [Sandbox URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-benji-zfw1gy?file=/src/auth/SignIn.jsx:0-422)

Comment: `Users` & `product` component should be come with left menu.